# Splitting CSVs into files named for one of the columns

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have CSVs like this:

```
apple,file1.txt
banana,file1.txt
carrot,file2.txt
```

How can I get it to place all of the items from the left column into files named with the items in the right column? E.g. `file.txt` would contain this list:

```
apple
banana
```

So far, I have this:

```
while read line 
do
    firstcolumn=$(echo $line | awk -F ",*" '{print $1}')
    secondcolumn=$(echo $line | awk -F ",*" '{print $2}')

done < Text/selection.csv
```

Comment: You did mean `file1.txt` would contain `apple` and `banana` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i > a[i]}' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
apple,file1.txt
banana,file1.txt
carrot,file2.txt

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i > a[i]}' file

[jaypal:~/Temp] ls file*
file      file1.txt file2.txt

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1.txt 
apple
banana

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2.txt 
carrot
```

**Update:**

You can also do something like this -

```
awk -F, '{print $1 > $2}' INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 4):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } { print $1 >> $2 }' infile
```

Comment: You can use `>` instead of `>>`. With `>` the output-file is erased before the first output is written to it. Subsequent writes to the same output-file do not erase output-file, but append to it. (This is different from how you use redirections in shell scripts.) If output-file does not exist, it is created. Source: [gnu awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

Comment: @JaypalSingh: Thank you. And now I realized that you had that solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash and under the assumption that all target files are empty or non-existing:

```
while IFS=',' read   item file ; do
  echo "$item" >> "$file"
done < "$infile"
```

Answer (score 1):

sed loves this stuff...

`sed "s%\(.*\),\(.*\)%echo \1 >> \2 %" inputfile.txt | sh`